# Errors while starting Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I got these errors while starting android studio. Please can anybody provide me solution for this:

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal
> error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
```

Comment: Have you tried to reïnstall it?

Comment: yes i have tried many times but still the errors are same

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: do you use the right JDK Version  (32/64bit)? is it just after fresh installation? Or do you add plugins? If you uninstall first, did you remove ALL old files ?

Comment: @HimaniPal see my answer

Answer (score 10):

Just go to `~/users/[your_username]/` and delete `.AndroidStudioXXX` . then restart android studio and don't import settings from the previous version.

Comment: This worked for me when upgrading to Android Studio 3.

Comment: I had to remove entire .AndroidStudio directory to make Android studio work but this way you will lose all configuration.

Answer (score -1):

WINDOWS 10:
What helped me is I went Computer Properties => Advanced => System Variables and deleted everything that says Android... 
There was AndroidSDK, AndroidAVD folder paths that are no longer existed in my system.

Answer (score -2):

FIRST make sure you have installed same 32-bit or 64-bit of JDK and ANDROID STUDIO. then do following

- Launch Studio
- Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure
- Go to the SDK's section
- Add a JDK
- Add the Android SDK that is bundled in inside the Android Studio installation folder

Then go back to creating a new project.

Comment: The app closes / crashes *at startup*, so the above cannot be done

Comment: this is for android studio....if you have problem regarding app then the issue must be something else... @strangetimes