# Android Studio doesn't open after updating it to 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio today. I installed the most recent version and then I applied the new 3.0 update manually, but it won't start...

Error Message that I get:

```
Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:213)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:49)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:346)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:276)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:510)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$9(ApplicationImpl.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:534)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:479)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:454)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:392)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:206)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.fromLocalPackage(BuildToolInfo.java:209)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getLatestBuildTool(AndroidSdkHandler.java:796)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.PlatformTarget.<init>(PlatformTarget.java:143)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargetMap(AndroidTargetManager.java:94)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargets(AndroidTargetManager.java:80)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargetFromHashString(AndroidTargetManager.java:154)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.findTargetByHashString(AndroidSdkData.java:218)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkAdditionalData.getBuildTarget(AndroidSdkAdditionalData.java:126)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidPlatform.parse(AndroidPlatform.java:90)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkAdditionalData.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidSdkAdditionalData.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidPlatform.getInstance(AndroidPlatform.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getEligibleAndroidSdks(IdeSdks.java:590)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getFirstAndroidSdk(IdeSdks.java:191)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:117)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.setupSdks(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:291)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.run(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:117)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.activateAndroidStudioInitializerExtensions(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:206)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.<init>(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:103)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:469)
    ... 28 more
```

Anyone know anything about this? I didn't want to reinstall the program, but if it's necessary, what choice do I have...

Thanks

Comment: `Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues` - -> you most likely have to reinstall, but either way report it to the issue tracker so they can fix it

Comment: have you tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39189235/3940133 ?

Comment: Zoe - I've reported, going to wait...

HendraWD - Tried right now, didn't help, just reduced a little the error list... Thanks

Comment: I believe it's working know (it's downloading components again), just deleted every folder in my user folder related to android. Thanks @HendraWD

Comment: Glad to help :). Just make sure you search for the error message first before ask a question, because it might have been answered.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved it deleting this file: file.template.settings.xml stored at the folder: /Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioX.X/options