# Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-3.1

My Android Studio encountered an error when starting it. Here is the snapshot:
[error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q2OK.png)

```html
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:213)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:49)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:346)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:276)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:515)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$9(ApplicationImpl.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:454)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:103)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:392)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:206)
    ... 16 more
```

It probably caused by an accidentally shutdown of my Mac. I tried the solution here [Errors while starting Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079384/errors-while-starting-android-studio). But it doesn't work.

Help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after trying all kinds of solutions for two days I finally figure out the right way. It seems there is no correct answer from Google so in case anyone encounter the same error in the future I would like to post the right solution here:

**Reason**: incorrectly install some plugins of Android Studio. You can find out this error caused by plugins from the first line of the error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.**plugins**.**PluginManager**$StartupAbortedException:
```

Therefore the reason is clearly the problem of some uncertain installed plugins.

**Solution**: find the plugins folder of Android Studio (in MAC open the application content of Android Studio; in Windows you can find that under C:\Users....AndroidStudioX.X\config\plugins) then delete the latest installed one.

That's it. You don't even need to restart your computer. Just reopen Android Studio and it should be able to work now!

I tried all kinds of solutions from Google but ended up with finding out the essential reason first. What a day.

Please vote me if this is helpful!

Answer (score 14):

I was facing the same issue on MacOS, and the accepted answer didn't fix it for me.

For me this error was fixed after running Android Studio with admin privilages.

***sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio***

Comment: this worked for me! Uninstalling didn't do the trick

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2021.2\Plugins
```

must be removed

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling IntelliJ Idea suffice.  No need to delete the IDE folders found in the user's home directory.

WARNING:  Install the full version with JDK, to be safe.  I got the same problem again later because I attempted to use the JDK I already had to run the tool.  This problem occurs if the JDK provided is not compatible with the JDK required by IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Hi, I reinstalled IntelliJ Idea. Problem's still here. How to install the full version with JDK?

Comment: There is a option while installing IntellijIdea to download JDK along with it

Comment: Thanks, is this the right place to download that? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=mac

Comment: I'm sorry but is there an option to download JDK altogether when you click download? In mine it will directly download a .dmg file.

Comment: while installation there is a option

Comment: I did not see any option... In mac it asked me to drag Intellj Idea to application then it's done... The only thing I have was to choose if I want to import settings from previously or customize. Do you have any clue?

Comment: then download it from oracle

Comment: restart your laptop

Answer (score 0):

I manage to run it by doing

1. run terminal
2. sudo /Applications/AndroidStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. until I Gave full control permissions to the `C:/Android` folder where your `adb` tools are installed.

- Right click on `C:/Android` -> "Properties"
- Go to "security" -> select your current user and then "Edit"
- check all Permissions.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
Uninstall your android studio first, then download the old version first. make sure java SDK and JRE are installed on your PC and added to the environment variable, After installing Old version Run Andriod Studio then update for the latest version